# How can I turn off wifi on thinkpad T460s?

Tags: wireless, thinkpad, wifi-hardware-switch

I have a T460s which has no physical switch for turning off the wifi, eg to save battery or when on airplanes.  The F8 key seems to have a relevant icon, but it seems to have no effect.  Other F keys do work, such as for changing the brightness or volume.  I don't have Windows installed on the machine, only Ubuntu Mate 16.04.  How can I turn off the wifi?

Comment: F8 works just find on my T560 with 16.04/16.10.  Is it an Intel Wifi card like mine or something else (non-Intel wifi has also been an option on some models).

Comment: 04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)

Answer (score 3):

In a terminal run

```
nmcli radio wifi off
```

When you want to turn it back on:

```
nmcli radio wifi on
```

As mentioned [in a comment by LiveWireBT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847718/how-can-i-turn-off-wifi-on-thinkpad-t460s/847725#comment1301716_847725) (thanks!) you can use the commands in custom keyboard shortcuts:

Go into the menu to set custom keyboard shortcuts

[image]

and add a new one for each `nmcli` command. Click where is says "disabled" and press the key combination you want to use (for example, <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>)

Comment: If that doesn't require root privileges one can make a custom keybinding in the keyboard menu or with xbindkeys. I for example added shift and ctrl modifiers to brightness up and down keys to have xbacklight work along the other keys in small and normal steps, but that's a different story. :)

Comment: @LiveWireBT good point! Yes, the nice thing about `nmcli` is it allows all users to control networking devices. I do that with `xbacklight` too since the Fn brightness keys don't work for me

Comment: Is nmcli any different than going to the network managed and unchceking the box enable wi-fi?  Does that actually shut down the device?

Comment: @user2777045 It is the same as unchecking the box - it's the software on/off switch and I guess you don't have a hardware on/off switch, unless you have an option in BIOS/UEFI firmware settings?